# Are there good jailbreak apps that will improve the performance of iPhone 3G?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone

I've an old iPhone 3G that I want to give it to my girl. She don't need it for play big games or stuff like that, but it's really slow in most of common tasks (access contacts, email, etc).

And since she isn't going to use many things the iPhone have, I was thinking in jailbreak it to see if there are apps that let you strip some of these things she wouldn't use.

Do you know jailbreak apps that strip functionality/features to iPhone 3G?

Or it'll going to be slower than now?

**EDIT**:
I expect something like remove unused characteristics like folders, or any stuff that make it slower. Kinda downgrading to 3.x but having compatibility with new apps.
Since overclocking is not safe for the phone (due to heat and functionality) I prefer to not consider it as an option, but thank you guys that suggested it!

Comment: Jailbreaking it will not help you, in fact it will make it slower. I would recommended doing a full restore.

Comment: @eliben Specially after the edit, I think this is a very good question. And jailbreaking doesn't make anything slower.

Answer (score 4):

Not a jailbreak solution, but... turn off SpotLight.

Go to Settings > General > Home > Search Results, and turn everything off.

This should result in a noticable speedup.

Comment: I have experienced better speed with this couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

NB - these instructions apply to iPhone OS 3.0, link to instructions for iOS 4.x at the bottom

You can run your iPhones processor at a higher-than-factory clock speed which should in theory make it faster.  However, it may cause the iPhone to run too hot so it's something to be aware of.  The steps are below:

1. Jailbreak the iPhone
2. [Use SSH](http://www.cultofmac.com/access-your-iphone-file-system-with-ssh-jailbreak-superguide/32134) to navigate to `/System/Library/System/System Configuration/PowerManagement.bundle/`
3. Rename file `com.apple.SystemPowerProfileDefault.plist` to something else
4. Restart your iPhone

Your iPhone will now run at the default speed for the processor it is built on.  You may experience instability as the iPhone was designed to run at a speed lower than the native speeds of the processors it's built on so there's a major health-warning on performing this step.

[iOS 4.x instructions](http://modmyi.com/forums/file-mods/726701-how-overclock-iphone-3g-3gs-4-a.html) thanks to @mankoff for his comment pointing out that the instructions had changed with the new iOS version.  I expect these will change again in future so be sure to check Google or the search box on this site for latest methods.

Comment: Significantly different instructions for iOS 4.X here: http://modmyi.com/forums/file-mods/726701-how-overclock-iphone-3g-3gs-4-a.html

Comment: Good point actually, I hadn't kept up to date on changes in this process with newer phones.  I'll amend the answer.  Thanks @mankoff

Comment: Great, thanks. I wasn't expecting to overclock the phone but limit functionality maybe. For example remove unused characteristics like folders, or any stuff that make it slower. Kinda downgrading to 3.x but having compatibility with new apps